# IllegalAccessError on Android Things

Tags: android-things

My app is throwing an `IllegalAccessError` after updating to the latest Android Things
preview. I have the following code to check for an OTA update:

```
UpdateManager manager = new UpdateManager();
manager.performUpdateNow(UpdateManager.POLICY_CHECKS_ONLY);
```

When I run this code I get the following error output:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void com.google.android.things.update.UpdateManager.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.example.android.things.screensettings.MainActivity' (...)
```

This code was working before, why has this started happening after the update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in Preview 7, Android Things API services are not constructed as new
instances. They are instead accessed as singletons via `getInstance()` to be
more in line with Android API paradigms.

Be sure to update your app to use the Preview 7 SDK:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.7-devpreview'
}
```

Then modify your code to use `getInstance()` instead:

```
UpdateManager manager = UpdateManager.getInstance();
manager.performUpdateNow(UpdateManager.POLICY_CHECKS_ONLY);
```

Review the Android Things [API reference](https://developer.android.com/things/reference/index.html)
to verify if any of the other APIs you are calling have changed.